# document.activeElement returns body in onblur handler

Tags: javascript, html, tabindex

Here is my HTML and JS:

```js
function invokeFunc() {
  // ajax request 
  alert(document.activeElement);
  // this returns body element in firefox, safari and chrome.
}
```

```html
<input id="text1" tabindex="1" onblur="invokeFunc()" />
<input id="text2" tabindex="2" onblur="invokeFunc()" />
```

I am trying set focus onblur on text boxes with proper tabindex set.

When I invoke the JavaScript function onblur and try to get `document.activeElement` it always returns the body element instead of the active element where focus is.

How can I return the active element rather than the body?

Comment: http://molily.de/weblog/javascript-fokus-zentral lists a cross-browser document.activeElement function.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Between leaving the old element and entering the new element the active element is indeed the document/body itself.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/u3uNP/

Comment: Thanks got it.. i think can make this call in async way to set focus on correct element after ajax event.

Comment: So how would you ensure that you find the new element and not the body?

Comment: @strava, see my answer.

Answer (score 16):

@ThiefMaster explained the reason, and I want to add a solution for getting the newly focused element:

Use `focusout` instead of `onblur`, and then utilize `relatedTarget` property:

```js
const inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; ++i) {
  inputs[i].addEventListener('focusout', (event) => {  
    console.log('newly focused element:', event.relatedTarget); 
  });
}
```

```html
<input id="text1" tabindex="1" />
<input id="text2" tabindex="2" />
```

Comment: In React use the `onBlur`, [reason](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37609092/15172167)

Comment: if you're ever in Omaha Nebraska, I owe you a beer 