# How to use relatedTarget (or equivalent) in IE?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, events, onblur

Apparently IE (11) has an issue with `relatedTarget`, for example on `blur` events. Is there an alternative for IE to get the `relatedTarget`?

Here is an example that produces an error in IE:
https://jsfiddle.net/rnyqy78m/

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If I look at this list: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/relatedTarget blur isn't included as having a standard secondary target. So I assume the secondary target on blur in chrome is non-standard.

If you replace blur by focusin or focusout, it also works for IE11 for me.

Comment: Thanks. I have only been using `blur` so far. But I guess that is because I am using Firefox and the doc you linked to states that Firefox does not support the `focusout` `relatedTarget`....

Comment: I hope to get an answer how to get it work across browsers here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/41299372/1981832

Comment: You could try feature detection. I don't have an up-to-date firefox atm, but try something like: `var eventName = MouseEvent.prototype.hasOwnProperty('relatedTarget') ? 'focusout' : 'blur';` Although I have no idea if firefox will return 'false' here. The idea is that you just check which one you can use before binding the event listener. You couldcheck the navigator, but that sounds more complex.

Comment: You could use [currentTarget](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget) in IE.

Comment: Swapping out 'blur' for 'focusout' and 'focus' for 'focusin' solved it for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 27):

It looks like IE11 sets document.activeElement to the next focused element before the blur event is called. So to handle blur correctly in all browsers including IE11 you could use something like

```
var target = evt.relatedTarget;
if (target === null) { target = document.activeElement; }
```

I adapted your fiddle to use this: https://jsfiddle.net/hukt0rhj/

Comment: Could shorten this to `var target = evt.relatedTarget || document.activeElement;` :)