# Stop body from getting focus

Tags: javascript, html

If I put the focus on the url edit in chrome and then press tab, then run `document.activeElement` in my console I get:

```
<body tabindex="-1" aurelia-app="main">...</body>
```

**Is there a way I can stop the `body` from getting the tab focus?**

Comment: What should get focus instead?

Comment: @epascarello - The next control in the focus "ring".  Meaning what ever the focus goes to when I hit tab a second time.

Comment: If you don't need to have body focused at any time, then just remove `tabindex` completely.

Answer (score 0):

As this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11299876/2671984):

> Between leaving the old element and entering the new element the active element is indeed the document/body itself.

I found if you don't want the body element to get focus do this

```
<body onfocus="blur();">
```